# How to organize array of dictionaries based on the value of a key within them?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of information stored as follows:

```
(
            {
        actual = "<null>";
        code = "AUTO.US";
        date = "2019-12-31";
        difference = "<null>";
        estimate = "-0.12";
        percent = "<null>";
        "report_date" = "2020-03-27";
    },
            {
        actual = "<null>";
        code = "APTX.US";
        date = "2019-12-31";
        difference = "<null>";
        estimate = "-0.5600000000000001";
        percent = "<null>";
        "report_date" = "2020-03-30";
    },
{

        actual = "<null>";
        code = "BLAH.US";
        date = "2019-12-31";
        difference = "<null>";
        estimate = "-0.5600000000000001";
        percent = "<null>";
        "report_date" = "2020-03-30";
    }
);
```

I would like to create an array of dictionaries, a key for each `report_date` that contains an array of the above dictionaries that match that date. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
(
        {
        "2020-03-27" =         (
                        {
                actual = "<null>";
                code = "AUTO.US";
                date = "2019-12-31";
                difference = "<null>";
                estimate = "-0.12";
                percent = "<null>";
                "report_date" = "2020-03-27";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        "2020-03-30" =         (
                        {
                actual = "<null>";
                code = "APTX.US";
                date = "2019-12-31";
                difference = "<null>";
                estimate = "-0.5600000000000001";
                percent = "<null>";
                "report_date" = "2020-03-30";
            },
        {

        actual = "<null>";
        code = "BLAH.US";
        date = "2019-12-31";
        difference = "<null>";
        estimate = "-0.5600000000000001";
        percent = "<null>";
        "report_date" = "2020-03-30";
    }
        );
    }
)
```

**For clarification, I want to end up with an array that holds dictionaries with the date as the day, which hold as their object an array of the original dictionaries that have report_date matching that key. So there could be more than one earnings dictionary in the array under the key.**

I appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` in Swift except in very rare circumstances.  You should use Swift arrays and dictionaries.  It would also help if you created an appropriate `struct` to hold your data rather than using raw dictionaries.  If your data is coming from JSON then you can use `Codable` to convert your data quite simply.

Working with what you have, however, you need to convert an array of `[String:String]` dictionaries to an dictionary of arrays of `[String:String], keyed by a`[String]`or the rather ugly`[String:[[String:String]]]`:

To do so, simply iterate over the initial array, adding each dictionary to the `[String:[[String:String]]]` dictionary:

```
func createEarningsDictionary(from earnings:[[String:String]] ) -> [String:[[String:String]]] {
    var arrayOfEarningsDicts = [String:[[String:String]]]()

    for earning in earnings {
        if let reportDate = earning["report_date"] {
            arrayOfEarningsDicts[reportDate, default:[[String:String]]()].append(earning)
    }
    return arrayOfEarningsDicts
}
```

If you used an `Earnings` struct rather than the `[String:String]` dictionary, you would have the more readable:

```
func createEarningsDictionary(from earnings:[Earnings] ) -> [String:[Earnings]] {
    var earningsDict = [String:[Earnings]]()

    for earning in earnings {
        earningsDict[earning.reportDate, default:[Earnings]()].append(earning)
    }
    return earningsDict
}
```

Comment: I am trying your answer but I have to use String:Any as there is an NSNumber in the original dictionary. For some reason though, the line that appends in the if let statement is returning nil. For clarification, I want to end up with an array that holds dictionaries with the date as the day, which hold as their object an array of the original dictionaries that have report_date matching that key. So there could be more than one earnings dictionary in the array under the key.

Comment: Yes, that is what my code does.  I tested it with a dictionary of `[String:String]` that I created from your sample data, adding an extra dictionary with the same `report_date`.  The difficulty you are having with having to use a dictionary of `[String:Any]` is why you should create an array of `Earnings` structs.  Is your data coming from JSON?

Comment: It is, yes. The way I have it represented above is how it comes from JSON.

Comment: The use definitely use `Codable` and a `JSONDecoder` to convert it to an array of structs - it will make your data much easier to deal with as well as eliminating `NSNumber`

Comment: Okay I will look into that. Thank you. However, I manually replaced NSNumber with its stringValue to test your code. It works but only for one of the earnings dictionaries. I only get one of the report dates but not the other one (passing two different dates). ["2020-03-27": [["report_date": "2020-03-27", "estimate": "-0.12", "code": "AUTO.US", "date": "2019-12-31"]]]

Comment: Here is my code from a playground and its output - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/b9c4a847cd641fb56d9bff07da66be52

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But I agree, I think I am going to go with the struct. I appreciate your help, leaving a good rating now.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit misleading, but:

the original data is an array of type `[[String: String]]` already, and the result that you require is an array of type `[[String: [String: String]]]`.

follow the following code to get there:

```swift
// building the original data
var dic1: [String: String] = [:]
dic1["actual"] = "<null>"
dic1["code"] = "AUTO.US"
dic1["date"] = "2019-12-31"
dic1["difference"] = "<null>"
dic1["estimate"] = "-0.12"
dic1["percent"] = "<null>"
dic1["report_date"] = "2020-03-27"

var dic2: [String: String] = [:]
dic2["actual"] = "<null>"
dic2["code"] = "APTX.US"
dic2["date"] = "2019-12-31"
dic2["difference"] = "<null>"
dic2["estimate"] = "-0.5600000000000001"
dic2["percent"] = "<null>"
dic2["report_date"] = "2020-03-30"

// the array of the original data
let array = [dic1, dic2]

// the interesting function
func sortThemOut() {
    var finalArray: [[String: [String: String]]] = []
    for dic in array {
        // get the `report_date` value from the original dictionary
        let reportDate = dic["report_date"] ?? "there was no value for the `report_date`"
        // create the new item that should be appended in the new array
        var newDic: [String: [String: String]] = [:]
        // set the key to the `reportDate`, and the value of that key to the original dictionary
        newDic[reportDate] = dic
        
        // append the new dictionary into the final array
        finalArray.append(newDic)
    }
    print(finalArray)
}
```

still I would highly recommend that you change this to convert the original data into an dictionary of type `[String: [String: String]]` instead, which I belive is what you really intent to get:

```swift
// the array of the original data
let array = [dic1, dic2]

func sortThemOut() {
    var finalDictionary: [String: [String: String]] = [:]
    for dic in array {
        // get the `report_date` value from the original dictionary
        let reportDate = dic["report_date"] ?? "there was no value for the `report_date`"
        // set the key to the `reportDate`, and the value of that key to the original dictionary
        finalDictionary[reportDate] = dic
    }
    print(finalDictionary)
}
```

which you can use like this:

```swift
    // key will represent the `report_date`, and the value will contain the rest of the object
    for (key, value) in finalDictionary {
        print("key: " + key)
        print("value: \(value)")
        
        // OUTPUT:
        
        // key: 2020-03-27
        // value: ["report_date": "2020-03-27", "estimate": "-0.12", "code": "AUTO.US", "difference": "<null>", "date": "2019-12-31", "actual": "<null>", "percent": "<null>"]
        
        // key: 2020-03-30
        // value: ["report_date": "2020-03-30", "estimate": "-0.5600000000000001", "date": "2019-12-31", "difference": "<null>", "percent": "<null>", "actual": "<null>", "code": "APTX.US"]
    }
    
    print(finalDictionary["2020-03-27"])
    // ["report_date": "2020-03-27", "estimate": "-0.12", "code": "AUTO.US", "difference": "<null>", "date": "2019-12-31", "actual": "<null>", "percent": "<null>"]
```

## UPDATE

Based on the clarifications in the comments below, the resulted object is going to be a dictionary of type `[String: [[String: String]]]', so the function would be:

```swift
func sortThemOut() {
    var finalDictionary: [String: [[String: String]]] = [:]
    for dic in array {
        // get the `report_date` value from the original dictionary
        let reportDate = dic["report_date"] ?? "there was no value for the `report_date`"
        // creating an array that will hold the original objects
        // try to get the array that was previously inserted (if a previous object with same report_date was inserted before, or assign an new empty array
        var objects = finalDictionary[reportDate] ?? []
        
        // append the object into the array
        objects.append(dic)
        
        // set the key to the `reportDate`, and the value of that key to the array of original objects
        finalDictionary[reportDate] = objects
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For clarification, I want to end up with an array that holds dictionaries with the date as the day, which hold as their object an array of the original dictionaries that have report_date matching that key. So there could be more than one earnings dictionary in the array under the key.